# AWS: Can i use one ip elastic for more than 1 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

I created some AWS instances that will be used to access customer servers, but customers want to limit server access to just a few fixed IPs, so I thought of using elastic ip for that, but as there are several instances I'm looking to see if there is any way to all instances use the same output ip, I tried to do this using the NAT gateway but I had no input access to the instances, is there any way to do this?

Comment: NAT Gateway is the correct (and only) way to achieve this. You need to focus on this part: "I tried to do this using the NAT gateway but I had no input access to the instances". Do you mean you couldn't SSH into the instances anymore? Add the details of that to your question, or ask a new question focusing on that.

Comment: No, you cannot attach one Elastic IP address to multiple Amazon EC2 instances.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your requirement is:

- Make requests coming from multiple Amazon EC2 instances 'appear' to be coming from the one IP address
- Keep the EC2 instances in a public subnet

#### Use a NAT Gateway

Using a NAT Gateway is certainly a good way to have multiple EC2 instances send traffic via a single IP address. However, it normally requires the instances to be in a private subnet, with Route Tables sending the Internet-bound requests through the NAT Gateway. This means that the instances are not directly reachable as they would be in a Public Subnet. A NAT Gateway is also fairly expensive because there is a charge for all traffic that passes through it.

#### Make your own proxy

Another option would be to have 'something' that relays the requests from the EC2 instances. For example, you could have a small EC2 instance (let's call it a 'proxy') with an Elastic IP address (which is static). The proxy could be configured to forward requests to the Internet. Then, you could configure the Route Table for the public subnet to direct traffic to this proxy -- but only for destination IP addresses of these particular external websites. This would make it act as a 'mini NAT Gateway', used only for specific destination addresses.

The proxy instance can be configured to forward traffic to the Internet. Here is a guide from [AWS NAT Instance creation · GitHub](https://gist.github.com/vgsuresh/10648492):

> In the EC2 console, disable source/dest checking by right clicking on the instance you want to use for NAT and choosing "Change Source / Dest Check".
>
> Create a security group having an inbound rule allowing ALL from 10.0.0.0/16 and associate it with your NAT instance.
>
> On the NAT instance, create /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/nat-setup as:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE
```

> chmod +x the script, then run it. This script will automatically be run when the machine reboots, so your NAT will survive a restart.
>
> Make sure all your private subnets have a default route to use the NAT instance as a gateway (create a route for 0.0.0.0/0 and associate it with your NAT instance in the route table(s) associated with your private subnets).
>
> Test your NAT by pinging something from an EC2 instance in a private subnet

This method requires a bit of technical knowledge and probably a bit of debugging, but it will be significantly cheaper than using a NAT Gateway.